# How to get nested directory structure into array or database?

Tags: php, recursion, iterator

I'm making a "photo uploader" project that can get all sub-files and sub-directory of specific folder.
I've used `iterator` to get files and directory :

```php
$path = dirname(__FILE__).'/';

use RecursiveIteratorIterator as RII;
use RecursiveDirectoryIterator as RDI;
use RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator as RCFI;

$directory = new RDI($path, RDI::SKIP_DOTS);

$filter = new RCFI($directory, function ($current, $key, $iterator) {
    return $current->isDir() || preg_match('/^.+(.jpe?g|.png|.gif)$/i', $current->getPathname()) > 0;
});
$iterator = new RII($filter, RII::SELF_FIRST);
```

After got them, I want their structure be store into database, into the following table :
`` column `id` is AUTO_INCREMENT ``

```
table `item`
| id | title | type | parent_id |
```

Like Unix, **everything is file, even dir**, I use column `type` to store **folder** or **file**, so I can use only one table.
For example, I got two files and two folder :

```
test (folder)
 -file1.png
 -subtest (folder)
  --file2.png
```

And I want to store them like this (just for example, the order of them is not important) :

```
| id |   title   |   type   | parent_id |
-----------------------------------------
| 1  |   test    |  folder  |    null   |
| 2  | file1.png |   file   |     1     |
| 3  |  subtest  |  folder  |     1     |
| 4  | file2.png |   file   |     3     |
```

I know how to get
I don't know how to get **every folder** and their **parent folder** structure into array, then store them into table like above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got a solution (Thanks [u/colshrapnel](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/n3p6jg/weekly_ask_anything_thread/gx0ooio/?context=3)) :
The easiest way would be to maintain a directory map manually. Say, after inserting the test directory you will get the id and store the full path in the array, `$map[$current->getPathname()] = 1;` and so on. Once getting a new entry, get the `dirname($current->getPathname())` and test it against the map to get the parent id

Hence the `test/subtest` should give you 3